# Addition of zero vector to a physical quantity

Tags: vectors, calculus

Today during an intro to vectors class, my physics teacher said that in physics unlike maths addition and subtraction of 0 does have a meaning.

He said " $t + 0$ would be greater than $t - 0$"

Can someone give any real-world example of what he meant? Or do I assume it to be a "dumbed down" way of expressing $\mathrm{d}\mathrm{x}$ or a small $\Delta x$ to the newer students?

Comment: Why do you call it the zero *vector*?

Comment: It is difficult to give an interpretation of a sentence out of context. As it is written, it is plainly wrong. There is no "physics sum" separate from "math sum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet so I'll just post it as an answer.

Yes he is.

In my personal experience, the infinitesimal adding usually comes as a fixing procedure. For example if you have something like $\frac{C}{x}$ and need information on what happens at $x=0$, you might add a parametric constant so that $\frac{C}{x+\varepsilon}$ is well behaved at $x=0$ and a parametric function of $\varepsilon$, which you send to zero in the end.

The fact that he mentioned it in vector calculus class is probably a coincidence, as adding an infinitesimal vector is not as trivial, since you have directions to choose etc.

It doesn't make intuitive sense without seeing it at work. A stunning example (and the only one I can think of at 3am) is *dimensional regularization* in Quantum Field Theory.
The shortest and most eye-catching description of it would be: there are integrals that diverge to infinity but shouldn't, so by setting the spacetime dimensions to $d=4-\varepsilon$ we can get other infinities to cancel them before sending $\varepsilon$ to 0 and only recovering the finite part we need (and indeed observe!)